# Разные цвета Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, color, pil, pillow

У меня проблема. Мне нужно создать список `colors`, в котором каждые `три` значения являются цветом `rgb`.

То есть первые три элемента списка это например: `234 56 145`. Где 234: кол-во красного, 56 зеленого, 145 синего.

Все числа должны быть случайными от `0` до `255`.
Нужно сделать так, что-бы все цвета не повторялись.
То есть чтобы не было двух одинаковых значений rgb.
Желательно приведите пример с кодом.

Comment: А в чём смысл? Ведь на глаз вы наверняка не сможете отличить, например, (255,255,255) от (254,254,254).

Comment: Мне не нужно определять на глаз отличия цвета, все определяет компьютер

Comment: Я просто говорю о том, что задача выглядит несколько бессмысленной с точки зрения реальной жизни. Хотелось бы знать, зачем это нужно.

Comment: @CrazyElf Возможно меня сейчас закидают гнилыми помидорками, но я пробую шифровать данные)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То-ли вы не точно сформулировали вопрос, то-ли ответ на него тривиален.
Если вот это требование точно,

```
Нужно сделать так, что-бы все цвета не повторялись. То есть чтобы не было двух одинаковых значений rgb.
```

то единственный ваш путь, что-бы добиться неповторения цвета -  сгенерировать все возможные комбинации цветов а потом извлекать из этого множества столько образцов, сколько надо.

Сделать это можно, например, вот так:

```
import random
zzz=[]
for i in range(256):
    for j in range(256):
        for k in range(256):
            zzz.append([i,j,k])
            
random.sample(zzz,5)
```

или вот так:

```
import itertools
zzz=list(itertools.product([i for i in range(256)],[j for j in range(256)],[k for k in range(256)], repeat=1))
random.sample(zzz,5)
```

Если же просто сделать random.sample(range(Х), 3) то получим повторы. Вот пример -  15 случайных образцов из 27 возможных комбинаций

```
import random
for i in range (15):
    print(random.sample(range(3), 3))
```

Результат:

```
[1, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 1]
[0, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 0, 2]
[0, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[0, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 0]
```

Повторов более чем достаточно.

Comment: Во-первых: это сильно повлияет на скорость. Во-вторых я ТОЧНО буду использовать менее 1 000 000 вариантов. Какова вероятность повтора цвета состоящего из 3 чисел? Цвет может отличаться хоть на единицу в любом r, g или b. Главное чтобы они не повторялись.

Comment: @Vecherr Не очень понял. С одной стороны, вы много раз повторили "Главное чтобы они не повторялись". С другой стороны говорите про вероятность. Одно из двух, или вы ПОЛНОСТЬЮ исключаете повторы, или вы считаете вероятность, которая, кстати, не такая уж и малая.  Что до времени -  не знаю, насколько оно критично, но у меня все 16 млн образцов генерируются за несколько секунд. Причем делается это один раз. А выбор из них -  вообще на время выполнения скрипта не влияет.

Comment: @passant вот только ваш код выдает не rgb набор, а список из 5 таких наборов (вот мне выдало ```[[41, 212, 129], [107, 168, 162], [170, 230, 254], [119, 241, 189], [211, 96, 240]]```

Comment: @n1tr0xs  А что вы хотели, что-бы выдавал генератор СЛУЧАЙНЫХ и ГАРАНТИРОВАННО РАЗНЫХ цветов? Три числа, каждое в диапазоне от 0 до 255. Это не набор RGB ??  А 5 задано исключительно  для примера.  Если это для вас проблема - замените 5 на 1.  Только вот ТС явно надо не один случайный цвет генерировать, а много.

Comment: @passant, видимо я не понял сразу чего хотел автор

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import random

random.sample(range(255), 3)
```

Comment: Насколько я понял, повторений не будет?

Comment: @Vecherr вы правильно поняли

Comment: К сожалению - повторения будут.

Comment: @passant прошу продемонстрировать.

Comment: @S. Nick  -  добавил пример к ответу ниже.

Comment: @passant прошу продемонстрировать на моем примере!

Comment: @S. Nick -  вы серьезно предлагаете сюда вставить листинг с 16 миллионами вариантов? Я показал, что такой подход в принципе дает повторяющиеся наборы. А 3, 33 или 255 разных значений в ваших переменных -  роли уже не играет. Просто искать совпадения будет труднее, но они будут.

Comment: @passant вы сделали утверждение, прошу его подтвердить.

Comment: Данный код создаст "rgb цвет" из неодинаковых значений, то есть r != g != b, но требуется из вопроса (насколько я понял) создавать цвета, которые не повторяются, а не их составляющие, то есть (r1, g1, b1) != (r2, g2, b2).

Comment: @DanBear Я имею ввиду что цвет может менятся даже на единицу в любом r или g или b. То есть первый цвет например: 255 67 42, а второй может быть 254 67 42. Главное чтобы не было повторов

Comment: И вообще я буду использовать менее 1 000 000 вариантов

Comment: @S.Nick@Vencherr https://repl.it/repls/MaroonLinenEngines

Answer (score 0):

Предложу и я свой смешной способ. Сначала код:

```
from random import shuffle

def get256random():
    l = list(range(256))
    shuffle(l)
    return l

def get256rgb():
    r256 = get256random()
    g256 = get256random()
    b256 = get256random()
    rgb = [(r,g,b) for (r,g,b) in zip(r256,g256,b256)]
    return rgb

s = set()
l = []
for i in range(10000):
    rgb = get256rgb();
    rgb_uniq = [(r,g,b) for (r,g,b) in rgb if not (r,g,b) in s]
    l.append(len(rgb_uniq))
    s.update(rgb_uniq)

print(l[:10])
print(l.index(255))
print(l[-10:])
print(len(s), len(s)/(10000*256))
```

Моя функция `get255rgb` гарантированно выдаёт 256 разных цветовых сочетаний. Её можно использовать повторно, получая так же пачку 256 новых не повторяющихся цветов, но все следующие пачки уже надо проверять - не встречались ли такие цвета в предыдущих пачках. В переменную `rgb_uniq` выбирается очередная пачка цветов, которые ещё не встречались. В конце проверка - а на какой итерации начинаются повторы? А сколько повторов бывает после 10000 циклов?

```
[256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256]
15
[216, 213, 219, 219, 225, 227, 211, 234, 232, 224]
2374357 0.927483203125
```

Итак, в начале повторов не было - выдавалось по 256 уникальных цветов.

Первый повтор встретился на 16-й итерации.

После 10000 циклов встречалось уже в среднем по 20% повторов.

Всего было сгенерировано 2374357 уникальных цветов, повторов суммарно было меньше 8%.

Но надо помнить, что это рандом и цифры с каждым запуском могут быть другие.

Answer (score -1):

Если без повторений, то можно попробовать так:

```
import random

for i in range(1):
    spisok = []
    a = random.randint(0, 256)
    b = random.randint(0, 256)
    c = random.randint(0, 256)
    if a != b and a != c and b != c:
        spisok.append(a)
        spisok.append(b)
        spisok.append(c)
        print(spisok)
```

Заранее извиняюсь за неграмотность кода, так как опыта мало.

Comment: Увы, это НЕ ответ на вопрос ТС.  Абсолютно.